# Unable to use Market because of my own mistake

Tags: google-play-store, root-access

Yesterday I rooted my Phone(Samsung Galaxy Ace), because I wanted to remove stock application Talk and Gmail. But I did something stupid, I went to /system/app and issued the following commands

```
rm *Google*
rm *Mail*
rm *Gmail*
rm *mail*
```

Now I am unable to use the market application, it opens and  then just closes itself. I have tried factory reset and it didn't help either. I am stuck because of this blunder. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned, I assume you don't have nandroid backup.

> A NANROID backup is basically a backup of your Android operating system from the phone’s NAND memory, saved to the storage card.

If you had that, you could have just restored the backup.

Now the alternative is, if you know the programs that were deleted by the performed command you could try getting the apk files and adding them in /system/app and rebooting the phone.

I thing the best and easy way now would be to get the stock ROM for your phone and flash it.

Comment: No, I dont have a nandroid backup :( , how can I flash my phone, please suggest me some easy-to-follow tutorial.

Comment: This is a very common question, I'd suggest you read our wiki, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device/

Comment: I have flashed my phone as per your suggestion and its working fine now, I just wanted to know how can I change the keyboard? is there any good app for that ?

Comment: I use this Gingerbread keyboard, https://market.android.com/details?id=com.moo.android.inputmethod.latin.free&feature=search_result.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the Market requires Talk to run, and you have to be signed into Talk for the market to work. This is your main issue. You will need to add them back via nandroid if you have it, otherwise you will have to reflash your rom.

You need to be really careful about which stock apps you remove as a lot of them are interdependent on one another. Check on XDA and Cyanogen sites for lists of which stock apps you can and can't remove.

Comment: In case you are wondering why Market  depends on Talk it's because push to device functionality is implemented as chat messages in Talk, and the market uses push to do Web install. In short don't remove Talk.